# Forces needed to redirect projectile

Tags: electromagnetism, forces

I need some help with a problem:

Suppose some object is traveling at constant velocity (in a vacuum) in a straight line, and I wanted to redirect said object to curve its path, say by 90°. Similar to how a spacecrafts trajectory is curved during a gravity assist, but done by a different force, Magnetism is this case specifically. How would I calculate the force needed?

Comment: Hint: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/magnetic/maspec.html#c2

Comment: @HiddenBabel Thanks, this seems to be exactly what I wanted!